# o365 JSON AverageRating

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have styled a (list) view with JSON. Using the column names (last part of the column url), this is all working fine. For a column that uses classification (star rating), the usual JSON code doesn't seem to work.

```
"elmType": "span",
"txtContent": "=[$AverageRating]",
"style": {
     "display": "block"
}
```

Anyone any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: What exactly the problem is? What is the internal name and data type of your column?

Comment: Is your column a ratings column?

Comment: Data type is (o365 standard) classification, turned on through library settings. Internal name (last part of column url) is AverageRating, which is also standard name. So, no custom name was given. All my custom named columns work perfect, except this (standard) column won't show.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps but as of now only the following columns types supports JSON formatting:

- Calculated
- Choice
- ContentType
- Counter (ID)
- Currency*
- Date/Time
- Hyperlink
- Location*
- Lookup
- Multi-Choice
- Multi-Line Text
- Multi-Person
- Number
- Person or Group
- Picture
- Single line of text
- Title (in Lists)
- Yes/No
- Formats for these column types can only be applied through Field Settings.

**official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint - Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh - i guess i'll have to wait until MS supports formatting for the classification/rating column. In my comment above i said 'through the library settings', but i meant list settings of course. When you turn on classification there, a rating column is created automatically. That's the column i'm talking about, not a custom made column.

Comment: Yes I understand you activated it from "Rating Settings" and it's data type is also "Ratings (0-5)". I think json formatting is not supported for this data type (But I have not found any article/documentation related to it).

Comment: Yes, i haven't found any article either. Thx anyway.

Comment: Please upvote ( ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.